# How to display validation errors on a joined model?

Tags: yii

On **Guestbook _form** view we have:

```
   <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'hs-guestbook-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )); 

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {   

        if($('#localized fieldset').length==1) 
        {

            $.ajax({
            success: function(html){
                $('#localized').append(html); 
                $('#localized fieldset:last-child').toggle()
            },
                            type: 'get',
                            url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('localized'); ?>',
                            data:
                                {
                                    index: 1
                                },
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'html'
                        });
        }                    
         else { 
            $('#localized fieldset:last-child').toggle();
         }

    });
    </script>

... and later down this view...

<div id="localized">
        <?php for($i=0; $i<count($local);$i++): ?>
            <?php if(isset($local[$i]))
                $this->renderPartial('_localized',array('model'=>$local[$i],'index'=>$i));
            ?>
            <?php endfor;?>
    </div>
```

The problem is:

We also need to display the `$form->error` on the other joined model (**GuestbookTr**) that I load here as `localized`. Obviously, we have no `_form.php` associated with that model, because it is joining this model (Guestbook).

Here's the partial view loaded on that Guestbook _form:

```
<fieldset>
    <label><?php echo $model->getAttributeLabel('title'); ?></label>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, "[$index]title"); ?>

    <label><?php echo $model->getAttributeLabel('description'); ?></label>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($model, "[$index]description"); ?>
</fieldset>
```

The question is rather simple dough:

#### How can we display the errors on this partial view, knowing that `$form->error` will give us: "Undefined variable form" ?

**Here are additional details:**

On our **GuestbookController** we call a new model like this:

```
 public function getExtraModelGuestTr()
 {
   $model = new HsGuestbookTr;
   if (isset($_POST['HsGuestbookTr']))
   {
     $model->attributes = $_POST['HsGuestbookTr'];
   }

    return $model;
 }
```

Then, on **create** we are using it like this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $this->layout = 'admin';

    $model=new HsGuestbook;

     $localized[] = $this->getExtraModelGuestTr();

     if(isset($_POST['HsGuestbook']))
     {

         if (($_POST['HsGuestbook']['status']) === '0') {
              $model->setScenario('Insert'); 
          } else {
              $model->setScenario('Publish'); 
      }
...
```

On **Guestbook model** we have:

```
public function rules()
{
 return array(
   array('name, category', 'required', 'on'=>'Insert'),
   array('name, category, image', 'required', 'on'=>'Publish'),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hand $form->error(); the $model variable of any model.
In your case you would have to make it accessable first and make their names disambiguous tho.

```
$model=new HsGuestbook;
$modelTr = new HsGuestbookTr;

$form->error($model,'name');
$form->error($modelTr,'name');
```

To create the $form variable you need to instantiate a new CActiveForm class as described at the documentation here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm

Comment: I did that on getExtraModel method showed above. :( I still can't get any `$form`to be uswd on the partial view, hence I can't display the errors related with those form fields.

Comment: Oh! didn't you create a form? (that is not done automatically!) see edits to my comment.

Comment: I've called CActiveForm on Guestbook _form. Inside that form, I am rendering a partial, calling it trough ajax, and it's on that partial view that I can't get to render any error message. Perhaps due to the ajax call ? I will add this snipped on my question.

Comment: You just want to reinitialize the $form in the Controller Action that takes the ajax call. Just use $form->error($modelTr,'name'); as i suggested before. The original $form variable from the last call will be gone, but you can just create a new CActiveForm object, it will do all the validation you need.